# Error ArtifactTransferException

Tags: java, maven-3, parent

Hi I am new in maven java. I want to make a maven project in Eclipse Juno, but by saving change in Eclipse this errors appears: my project is like: [example](http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/developer/programming-guide/ows-services/implementing.html).

```
- Archive for required library: 'C:/Users/Iman/.m2/repository/org/geoserver/main/2.2/main-2.2.jar' in project 'hello' cannot be read or is not a valid ZIP file
- ArtifactTransferException: Failure to transfer it.geosolutions.imageio-ext:imageio-ext streams:jar:1.1.4 from http://download.java.net/maven/2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of maven2-repository.dev.java.net has elapsed or updates are forced. Original error: Could not transfer artifact it.geosolutions.imageio-ext:imageio-ext-streams:jar:1.1.4 from/to maven2 repository.dev.java.net (http://download.java.net/maven/2): The operation was cancelled.
- ArtifactTransferException: Failure to transfer it.geosolutions.imageio-ext:imageio-ext-streams:jar:1.1.4 from http:// maven.geo-solutions.it/ was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of geosolutions has elapsed or updates are forced. Original error: Could not transfer artifact it.geosolutions.imageio-ext:imageio-ext-streams:jar:1.1.4 from/to geosolutions (http://maven.geo-solutions.it/): The operation was cancelled.
- ArtifactTransferException: Failure to transfer org.jaitools:jt vectorbinarize:jar:1.2.0 from http://maven.restlet.org was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of maven-restlet has elapsed or updates are forced. Original error: Could not transfer artifact org.jaitools:jt-vectorbinarize:jar:1.2.0 from/to maven-restlet (http://maven.restlet.org): The operation was cancelled.
- Missing artifact it.geosolutions.imageio-ext:imageio-ext-streams:jar:1.1.4
- ArtifactTransferException: Failure to transfer org.jaitools:jt-vectorbinarize:jar:1.2.0 from http://download.osgeo.org/webdav/geotools/ was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of osgeo has  elapsed or updates are forced. Original error: Could not transfer artifact org.jaitools:jt-vectorbinarize:jar:1.2.0 from/to osgeo (http://download.osgeo.org/webdav/geotools/): The operation was cancelled.
- ArtifactTransferException: Failure to transfer org.jaitools:jt-vectorbinarize:jar:1.2.0 from http://download.java.net/maven/2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of maven2-repository.dev.java.net has elapsed or updates are forced. Original error: Could not transfer artifact org.jaitools:jt-vectorbinarize:jar:1.2.0 from/to maven2 repository.dev.java.net (http://download.java.net/maven/2): The operation was cancelled.
- ArtifactTransferException: Failure to transfer org.jaitools:jt vectorbinarize:jar:1.2.0 from http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced. Original error: Could not transfer artifact org.jaitools:jt-vectorbinarize:jar:1.2.0 from/to central (http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): The operation was cancelled.
- ArtifactTransferException: Failure to transfer it.geosolutions.imageioext:imageio-ext-streams:jar:1.1.4 from http://maven.restlet.org was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of maven-restlet has elapsed or updates are forced. Original error: Could not transfer artifact it.geosolutions.imageio-ext:imageio-ext-streams:jar:1.1.4 from/to maven-restlet (http://maven.restlet.org): The operation was cancelled.
- ArtifactTransferException: Failure to transfer org.jaitools:jtvectorbinarize:jar:1.2.0 from http://maven.geo-solutions.it/ was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of geosolutions has elapsed or updates ar forced. Original error: Could not transfer artifact org.jaitools:jt-vectorbinarize:jar:1.2.0 from/to geosolutions (http://maven.geosolutions.it/): The operation was cancelled.
- ArtifactTransferException: Failure to transfer it.geosolutions.imageioext:imageio-ext-streams:jar:1.1.4 from http://download.osgeo.org/webdav/geotools/ was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of osgeo has elapsed or updates are forced. Original error: Could not transfer artifact it.geosolutions.imageio-ext:imageio-ext-streams:jar:1.1.4 from/to osgeo (http://download.osgeo.org/webdav/geotools/): The operation was cancelled.
- Missing artifact org.jaitools:jt-vectorbinarize:jar:1.2.0
- ArtifactTransferException: Failure to transfer it.geosolutions.imageioext:imageio-ext-streams:jar:1.1.4 from http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced. Original error: Could not transfer artifact it.geosolutions.imageio-ext:imageio-ext-streams:jar:1.1.4 from/to central (http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): The operation was cancelled.
```

Answer (score 0):

m2eclipse is using the proxy specified in .m2/settings.xml but if relolving an archetype it ignores the nonProxyHosts.

If you get such a connection error for all new artifacts: m2eclipse uses an embedded Maven instance by default, not your external Maven installation. The internal Maven instance might not use the same Maven settings like your external one (e.g. %USERPROFILE%/.m2/settings.xml), which then might lead to the internal Maven instance not being able to connect through your proxy.

You can use the Eclipse preferences to add your external Maven installation and to have it be used for running Maven commands from inside Eclipse.

Try turning your m2e plugin off.